# Google Calendar app entries on Android Device inconsistent with web browser entries

Tags: google, google-calendar

I cannot make sense of the entries on my Google Calendar for android application. When compared with the web version of Google Calendar (see screenshots below), I can see the following differences:

- Google Calendar for Android shows two accounts (both are associated with exactly the same e-mail address, and this is exactly the same e-mail address I use to access Google Calendar via a web browser). To me this is confusing: why two accounts with the same name? And why two of them, when on the PC only one of them shows up?
- Secondly, the entries (the calendar names, if this is what they are), are different. The Android app displays "Events" (but I have no calendar called Events on the web interface), Samsung Calendar (no clue as to what this is), "My calendar" (but on the web interface I have "My calendars", i.e., more than one), etc... you can see that besides "Birthdays" and "Holidays" I cannot see all the other calendars which can be seen and I have added via the web interface.

**Can someone please explain these differences?**

[image]

[image]